# Assigning a column of the database to csv column with mongoimport

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoimport

i have a script in python that gets a csv from a directory and import it to a table.

Im running this command everything works fine.

```
mongoimport -d db_test -c test_table --type csv --file filepath --headerline
```

My question is: can i define the correspondent csv file header column to the table column name?

For example, my table has the fields field1, field2 and field3 because the headers on the CSV are field1, field2 and field3. But i need to change the columns name of my table to fieldtest1, fieldtest2 and fieldtest3 but i can change the csv header names.
When i import the csv i would like that the field1 from csv header correspond to the column fieldtest1 of my table. Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you leave off the `--headerline` argument and specify the fields with [`--fields`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption--fields) instead, it will import the header line as a document and you can just remove it later.  You will have to specify all the fields though, there is no way to pick and choose or merge between the two methods with `mongoimport` at the moment.

Comment: thanks, i thought i could do it automatically. I end up replacing the header of the csv with the one i want at the moment i import the file.